# Control Actions-on-Google Media-Response (e.g. start at minute 3)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i want to develop an google-action. (ideally using dialogflow).

but the google-action needs some features where i couldn't find a solution, and i'm not sure if it's even possible.

My Usecases:
The google action starts a mps. someone stops and exits the google action, and if the user starts the google action again, i would resume the mp3.

but i couldn't find a solution where i can determine the "offset", when the user stops the mp3. 
and even i would have this offset, i didn't find a solution how to tell google assistant, that i want to play the mp3, but starts at e.g. Minute 51.

I would be really wondered, it the google action possibilitys are so extremly restricted.

can someone confirm, that this usecases are not possible, or can someone give me a hint how to do it?

i only found this one, which is restricted to start a mp3 at beginning. 
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

To start an mp3 file at a certain point you can try the SSML  tag and its clipBegin property.

> **clipBegin** - A TimeDesignation that is the offset from the audio source's beginning to start playback from. If this value is greater than or equal to the audio source's actual duration, then no audio is inserted.

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

To use this, your mp3 file has to be hosted using **HTTPS**

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using ssml is not an option. 
Because my mp3 is longer. And the Documentation about ssml says: 

"120 seconds maximum duration. If you want to play audio with a longer duration, consider implementing a media response."

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't know about the 120 maximum on the audio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conversational actions (instead of dialogflow) where media responses allow using a `start_offset`

```
....
"content": {
        "media": {
          "start_offset": "2.12345s",
...
```

For more details see
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media#MediaResponseProperties

Even conversational actions seem to be the "newest" technology for google actions. Or at least released recently.